# 2 divs - same height different widths, fixed and dynamic

Tags: html, css

OK, I edited my question and code to easily show what I mean. I need to have:

1. "menu" - positioned-left, min-height=500px, width=250px - at all times.
2. "content" -  positioned on the right side of "menu", dynamic width to take all remaining space.
3. Same height for "menu" and "content" at all times. No matter there will be 1 box  or 100 inside "content".
4. "Boxes" should be lined up from left to right and if there are more, they should stretch height of "content" and "menu" should follow the same height.

```
<div class="header" style="height:150px; background-color:black;" >
</div>

<div class="navbar" style="height:40px; background-color:yellow;" >
</div>

<div class="menu" style="min-height:500px; width:250px; background-color:orange; float:left;" >
</div>

<div class="content" style="height:auto; background-color:blue; float: left; " >

    <?php for ($col = 0; $col < 50; $col++)
            {
    ?><div class="box" style="width:80px; height:80px; background-color:white; margin:10px;" ></div><?php
        }  
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: It will if you select the code and click on the `{}` button in the editor. The selection will then be formatted as code.

Comment: Why is this question tagged `php`? The issue has _nothing_ to do with php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 150px 40px minmax(500px , 1fr)
}

.header, .navbar {
  grid-column: 1 / -1
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 80px);
  align-content: start;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.box {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='header'>
    Header
  </div>
  <div class='navbar'>
    Navbar
  </div>
  <div class='menu'>
    Menu
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
    <div class='box'>box</div>
    <div class='box'>box</div>
    <div class='box'>box</div>
    <div class='box'>box</div>
    <div class='box'>box</div>
    <div class='box'>box</div>
    <div class='box'>box</div>
    <div class='box'>box</div>
    <div class='box'>box</div>
    <div class='box'>box</div>
    <div class='box'>box</div>
    <div class='box'>box</div>
    <div class='box'>box</div>
    <div class='box'>box</div>
    <div class='box'>box</div>
    <div class='box'>box</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, this perfectly answers my question.Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is easier to achieve with flexbox, as shown in the solution below.

```css
.header {
  height: 150px; 
  background-color: black;
}

.navbar {
  height: 40px; 
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container {
  min-height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.menu {
  min-height: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px; 
  background-color: orange; 
}

.content {
  min-height: 500px;
  background-color: blue; 
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  width: 80px; 
  height: 80px; 
  background-color: white; 
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
</div>

<div class="navbar">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it is very close but still, the "menu" width changes when changing size of the window.